# XML parser don't know whitespace length

Tags: xml, excel, vba, domdocument, ixmldomelement

I have the following XML sample.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:f="http://kbcfp.com/BoTech/Inferno/Fault"
    xmlns:base="http://kbcfp.com/BoTech/Inferno/Base" xmlns:h="http://kbcfp.com/BoTech/Inferno/Header" xmlns:ep="http://torstonetech.com/Inferno/FDE">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <h:optLockSeqNumbers>
    <h:values><h:editSequenceNumber>1</h:editSequenceNumber><h:modifiedDateTime>2015-01-21T15:33:10+06:30</h:modifiedDateTime><h:modifiedUserId>1005</h:modifiedUserId><h:objectId>100100049</h:objectId><h:optimisticLockObjTypeId>11</h:optimisticLockObjTypeId></h:values>
    </h:optLockSeqNumbers>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ep:AccountAttrs><ep:accountId>100100049</ep:accountId><ep:attrId>100001896</ep:attrId>
    <ep:AccountAttrs><ep:accountId> </ep:accountId><ep:attrId>100001896</ep:attrId></ep:AccountAttrs>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I have to read this XML and expected output as below.

```
1st  ep:accountId 100100049
     ep:attrId 100001896
2nd  ep:accountId  <!-- want to write 1 space in these place -->
     ep:attrId 100001896
```

This is my XML parser code.

```
Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
xmlDoc.LoadXML aboveXMLStringVale
Call readNode(xmlDoc.ChildNodes)

public Function readNode(ByRef nodes AS MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList)
Dim xmlNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
For Each xml Node In nodes
  If xmlNode.nodeType = NODE_TEXT Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("xxx").Cell(row,column) = xmlNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.nodeName
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("xxx").Cell(row,column) = xmlNode.ParentNode.nodeName
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("xxx").Cell(row,column) = "'" & xmlNode.NodeValue
  End If

  If xmlNode.HasChildNodes Then 
   Call readNode(xmlNode.ChildNodes)
  End If
Next
End Function
```

Code is fine and show the output if XML childnode text have no space value.
My code condition is check XML element tag have value or not by using 
**"If xmlNode.HasChildNodes Then"** condition.
 For white space case, there is no childnode and no length for xmlNode object.
So I can't check the condition and can't write whitespace element tag value and them coding will skip to next XML element tag.

I am really appreciate for any help and suggestion.

**Addition:**
This  **"If xmlNode.HasChildNodes Then"**  condition is check xmlNode childnode length.
eg. 
`if childnode length > 0 return true, if not return false.`

As my whitespace case, condition will always return false because childnode lenght is 0 for whitespace value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You XML parser ignores the whitespace node. Try changing the [DOMDocument.preserveWhiteSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa925540.aspx) property before loading the XML.

```
Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
xmlDoc.preserveWhiteSpace = true
xmlDoc.LoadXML aboveXMLStringVale
```

HINT: You're using the XML parser to parse SOAP. Do you don't have SOAP parser/library available?

Comment: Do you don't have SOAP parser/library available? No I think, if you have please show sample. By the way, thank you for your code sample.It's work. But need to change xmlDoc.preserveWhiteSpace = false to xmlDoc.preserveWhiteSpace = true.If you revised your answer false to true, I will accept it.